# What's the lunchbox for?

Tags: fallout-4

I found a lunchbox while scavenging. When I picked it up it made a sound, suggesting it might be important. Is it useful beyond simply being a piece of scrap?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Picking up a Vault-Tec lunchbox will open it and spawn a random item, which will fall out of the lunchbox and be on the floor somewhere near by. You get to keep the lunchbox after opening it and it can be used in crafting.

From experience it's largely junk items that you can use in crafting. It's possible to save your game before opening the lunchbox and reload it to try for another item as the item is spawned at the point you open the lunchbox.

Comment: My best find so far is an `Ice cold Nuca-Cola Quantum`, but I also found a `Sentry Bot Model` which seems useless except for being worth 100 caps. The actual lunchbox is *probably* useful to craft with, as in Fallout 3 you could make bombs with them.

Comment: It's also a reference to Lunchboxes in Fallout Shelter, where they provide random resources / items.  They seem to have the same confetti effect when opened.

Comment: I've opened 3 and found spoons and a fork.

Comment: I've opened several, and if anything popped out I didn't see it. Does it fly out and land somewhere, or what?

Comment: @DCShannon, that's a bit unusual. They usually "pop" out, but land withing inches of the box. Kind of a late answer to your comment, so you may have noticed that already.

Comment: @DangerZone Yes, I have noticed that now. Thanks. The first character I made had very low luck. My next character had much higher luck, and I see stuff pop out all the time.

Comment: Kalina, I started to edit this to make it clearer that the item pops out on the ground for you to pick up, but you make it sound like it gets picked up automatically, which is wrong, so I didn't want to change your intent.

Comment: @DCShannon don't worry about that, my intent is always to provide the correct answer and be as helpful as possible so as long as your edits work towards that goal they're fine by me

Answer (score 14):

When you activate a Vault-Tec lunch box, an item may pop out for you to pick up. My experience indicates that this depends on your character's Luck.

[This page at Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_lunchbox) lists some possible items you might find. I don't think it's a complete list. That page makes it sound as if something always pops out. This may be the case, but I remember having nothing pop out before. Perhaps I just didn't notice it.

The item is usually some junk, like a spatula. You can still pick up the lunch box, whether you pick up the item or not.

The lunch box can be used to make bottlecap mines.

Comment: Definitely a more accurate answer. Especially since it focuses on an actual use of the lunchbox, and not just the potential random item inside.